# Draw a stripe with Box decoration

Tags: flutter

I want to decorate a container with a single stripe down the middle with white on each side like in the picture, I'm guessing I need to use Linear Gradient but I am struggling to get it right.Any Ideas?

[Single Stripe Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d5uC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, You need to create a container and make a child of it as Stack and further create a container with aligned it to center. Give it some width and decorate it with linear gradient that's all

Here's some code I've written to help you. Feel free to customize on top of it and use within your app. Cheers!

```
Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you this is going to work! very simple actually I deserve to be downvoted and never answer questions in my life i guess ;)